# how to programically check current week is first week of month

Tags: android

how toget the first monday of week??? im creating an school app which display lunch for semester  which start from 1st jully 2013  which is monday so its prsent frist week of month another menu and   give second week of month another menu so first week of month its show Monday1, tuesday1,wednesday1,thursday1,friday1,      second week of month i will lik to check  monday2,tuesday2, wednesday2,thursday2,friday2, below is my calender how i will modify this code to detect it is frist week of month  this is secon week of month in thirdweek again values will change to m1.t1,w1,t,1  actully lunch is provide for 2 week and rechudule again so how i will detect programiclally  current week is first week of month and current week is second week of month

```
         public class HoyahCalendar extends Activity {
public static int mYear;
public static int currentIndex = -1;
public static int mMonth;
public static int mDay;
public static String[][] a = new String[6][7];
String  January="January";
String  February="February";
String  March="March";
String  April="April";
String  May="May";
String  June="June";
String  Jully="Jully";
String  August="August";
String  September="September";
String  October="October";
String  November="November";
String  December="December";
String  Monthname;

 TextView date_today;
 ImageView last_month;
 ImageView next_month;

 ImageView last_week;
 ImageView next_week;
 String completedate2;
 Date dt1;


 Button e00;
 Button e01;
 Button e02;
 Button e03;
 Button e04;
 Button e05;
 Button e06;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getIntent().setAction("Already created");


    date_today = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_today);
    last_month = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.last_month);
    next_month = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next_month);
    last_week = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.last_week);
    next_week = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next_week);
  //
   //       e00 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e00);
   //       e01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e01);
    //      e02 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e02);
     //     e03 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e03);
     //     e04 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e04);
     //     e05 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e05);
   //       e06 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e06);




    e00 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e00);
    e01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e01);
    e02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e02);
    e03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e03);
    e04 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e04);
    e05 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e05);
    e06 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e06);

    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // / setListeners();

    last_month.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 1) {
                mYear -= 1;
                mMonth = 12;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, 1);
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                mMonth -= 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, 1);
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    next_month.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 12) {
                mYear += 1;
                mMonth = 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, 1);
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                mMonth += 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, 1);
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    last_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mMonth == 1) {
                mYear -= 1;
                mMonth = 12;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "last");
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                // mMonth -= 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "last");
                showOnScreen();
            }
        }
    });

    next_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 12) {
                mYear += 1;
                mMonth = 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "next");
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == 4) {
                    HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = 4;
                    // mMonth += 1;
                }

                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "next");
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
    showOnScreen();
     completedate2= String.format("%02d", mDay)+ "/"+String.format("%02d", 
          mMonth) +"/"+mYear;


     String input_date=completedate2;
      SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    try {
        dt1 = format1.parse(input_date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      SimpleDateFormat format2=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); 
      String finalDay=format2.format(dt1);
         Toast.makeText(this, "Today is is"+ finalDay, 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();






}

public void showOnScreen() {

    if (mMonth ==1) 
    {
        Monthname="January";
        }
    else 
        if (mMonth ==2) { 
            Monthname="February";
            }

        else
    if (mMonth ==3) { Monthname="March";}

   else 
        if (mMonth ==4) { Monthname="April";    }

        else
    if (mMonth ==5) { Monthname="May";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==6) { Monthname="June"; }
        else
    if (mMonth ==7) { Monthname="July";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==8) { Monthname="August";   }
        else
    if (mMonth ==9) { Monthname="September";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==10)    { Monthname="October";  }
    if (mMonth ==11)    { Monthname="November";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==12)    { Monthname="December"; }


    date_today.setText(  Monthname + "  " +mYear);
    e00.setText("" + a[0][0]);

    if(e00.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))

//  if(e00.getText().toString().equals(mDay))

    {e00.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button1 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    e01.setText("" + a[0][1]);

    if(e01.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))


    {
        e01.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));

    Toast.makeText(this, "Button2 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    e02.setText("" + a[0][2]);
    if(e02.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))

    {e02.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button3 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    e03.setText("" + a[0][3]);
    if(e03.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))
    {e03.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button4 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    e04.setText("" + a[0][4]);
    if(e04.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))
    {e04.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button5 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    e05.setText("" + a[0][5]);
    if(e05.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))
    {e05.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button6 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    e06.setText("" + a[0][6]);
    if(e06.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay)))
    {e06.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button7 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}









  public class ShowCalendar {
  int mYear;
   int mMonth;
    int mDay;
public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth){
    this.mYear = mYear;
    this.mMonth = mMonth;
    calculateMonthFirstday();
}
public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay){
    this.mYear = mYear;
    this.mMonth = mMonth;
    HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = 0;

    this.mDay = mDay;
    calculateMonthFirstday();
}


public int getmDay() {
    return mDay;
}





public void setmDay(int mDay) {
    this.mDay = mDay;
}





public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay, String time){
    this.mYear = mYear;
    this.mMonth = mMonth;
    if (time == "next"){
        HoyahCalendar.currentIndex++;
        if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == 5){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex--;
        }
        this.mDay = mDay + 7;
    } else if (time == "last"){
        HoyahCalendar.currentIndex--;
        if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == -1){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex++;
        }
        this.mDay = mDay - 7;
    }
    calculateMonthFirstday();
}

public void calculateMonthFirstday(){
    int month, first_day=0;
    if((mYear%4==0 && mYear%100!=0)||(mYear%400==0))
        month=1;
    else
        month=0;

    int y, y12, c, c12, m, d;
    y = mYear%100;
    y12 = (mYear-1)%100; //only for January and February
    c = mYear/100;
    c12 = (mYear-1)/100;
    m = mMonth;
    d = 1;

    switch(mMonth){
    case 1: {first_day = y12 + y12/4 +c12/4 - 2*c12 + 26*(13 + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 2: {first_day = y12 + y12/4 +c12/4 - 2*c12 + 26*(14 + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 3: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 4: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 5: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 6: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 7: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 8: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 9: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 10: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 11: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 12: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    }
    if(first_day<0)
        first_day = 7 - (Math.abs(first_day))%7;//first_day每月第一天星期几
    else
        first_day = first_day%7;

    switch(mMonth){
        case 1: {CalculateCalendar(1,first_day,31);break;}
        case 2: {CalculateCalendar(2,first_day,28+month);break;}
        case 3: {CalculateCalendar(3,first_day,31);break;}
        case 4: {CalculateCalendar(4,first_day,30);break;}
        case 5: {CalculateCalendar(5,first_day,31);break;}
        case 6: {CalculateCalendar(6,first_day,30);break;}
        case 7: {CalculateCalendar(7,first_day,31);break;}
        case 8: {CalculateCalendar(8,first_day,31);break;}
        case 9: {CalculateCalendar(9,first_day,30);break;}
        case 10:{CalculateCalendar(10,first_day,31);break;}
        case 11:{CalculateCalendar(11,first_day,30);break;}
        case 12:{CalculateCalendar(12,first_day,31);break;}
    }
}

public void CalculateCalendar(int month_no, int week_no, int month_days){

    int i, s, targetRow = 0;
    int currentDay;
    if (this.mDay == 0){
        mDay = 1;
        currentDay= HoyahCalendar.mDay;     
    }else {
        currentDay = this.mDay;
    }
    //String[][] a = new String[6][7];
    for (i=0;i<week_no;i++)
        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = "";

    for(i=week_no; i<week_no + month_days; i++){
        s = i - week_no + 1;
        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = String.valueOf(s);
        if (s == currentDay && HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == -1){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = i/7;
        }
    } 
    for (i=0; i<7;i++){
        if (HoyahCalendar.a[HoyahCalendar.currentIndex][i] == null){
            HoyahCalendar.a[0][i] = "";
        }else{
            HoyahCalendar.a[0][i] = 
     HoyahCalendar.a[HoyahCalendar.currentIndex][i];
        }

    }
    for(i=week_no+month_days; i<42; i++)


        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = "";
}

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH`. If the week is the first week, then you will get `1` as value. You may do something like:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
int weekNo1 = date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

If you see [WEEK_OF_MONTH](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_MONTH), it says:

`This indicates the week number within the current month. The first week of the month, as defined by getFirstDayOfWeek() and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(), has value 1`

If you want to obtain this for any other month, just set the date in calendar for getting the week of the month like:

```
date.set(2013, Calendar.JANUARY, 25); // Set any other months etc
```

You can set first day of the week as Monday using

```
date.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

**Update**

Altogether

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
int weekNo1 = date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

This will tell it to set the first day to week to Monday for each month. So now for the current date `date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);` will tell you that which is the current week within the current month keeping in mind that the first day of the week is Monday. I think you can visualize `date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)` function now to give result ass the number of times `Monday` ( for this examples) has come in this current month.

Comment: no but this work only currrent week how i will check this for last month or next month

Comment: i want to detect week from monday not first day of week  check from first monday of month

Comment: You can set first day of the week using 
    `cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);`

Comment: in my app semester start from frist jull of 2013 which is monday so i will check at every month first week of month start from monday so next will be second week of month and so on

Comment: u mean replac this line nt weekNo1 = date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);  with date.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);

Comment: shobhit puri  where i fit this line  cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);??

Answer (score 1):

```
  Calendar ca1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        ca1.set(2013, Calendar.AUGUST, 25);
        cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY)
        int wk = ca1.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println("Week of Month :" + wk);
```

Comment: i want to check from first monday of month not frist day of month so i want to count month from first monday of  month

Comment: ur code is work but u give innput ca1.set(2013, Calendar.AUGUST, 25);  how i will check from first jully of 2012 till 2013 december i is frst wekk or 2nd